# How to prove this quasi-geometric trigonometric series identity without induction

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, summation

$$\frac{2}{\sin{x}}\sum_{r=1}^{n-1} \sin{rx}\cos{[(n-r)y]} \equiv \frac{\cos{(nx)}-\cos{(ny)}}{\cos{x}-\cos{y}} - \frac{\sin{(nx)}}{\sin{x}}$$

The identity can be tediously proven using the Axiom of Induction.

I am looking for other means of proving this identity.

Comment: Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro

Comment: I do not see how the summation you provided can be re-arranged into the identity above.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: First use $2\sin(x)\cos(y)=\sin(x+y)+\sin(x-y)$, then apply $2i\sin(u)=e^{iu}-e^{-iu}$.

Comment: Tried that, didn't get to the answer. Even though I should have.

Comment: Please post your calculations so that we see, where something went wrong.

Comment: I have discarded all my papers which have my attempts on proving the identity. I will try this again soon.